# Selecting only one character value from a df with multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

so I have a df with 5 columns (col1, col2, col3, col4, length). Columns 1:4 randomly contain values A to F or contain an NA. I would like create a new df that only contains the value F and the length value that comes with it. So is the first rows of the df are:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4 length
1  A    B    F    C    15
2  F    D    E    A    12
3  F    F    NA   NA   3
4  F    NA   NA   NA   8 
5  A    D    C    A    11
6  F    F    F    F    10
```

I would like to keep row 3, 4 and 6.

Each time I select the value F I get a new df that in the first column contains an F, but I do not succeed to include the other columns as well, then it shows A:E in col2 or col3 for example. I would like to have a df that only contains F or NAs.

If i try anything like this:

```r
selected_new <- selected_df[selected_df$col1 == "F" & selected_df$col2 == "F" &
                            selected_df$col3 == "F" & selected_df$col4 == "F", ]
```

It shows a df that has an F in every cell, like row 6 in the example. But this way information from row 3 and 4 is lost and is not included in the df. I have tried variations of this code, but I did not figure it out.

If anyone can help, thank you!

Any variation including logical operators like "|" or "&" did not get me far and continued to show other values aside from F or NA.

Comment: `df[rowSums(df[1:4] != 'F', na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ]`

Comment: Hi thank you! I have tried your code but it selects rows that only contain F, other rows that would contan F NA NA NA for example are still left out. Is there any alteration I could make these are included as well in the new df?

Comment: Do you mean the 4th row in your example data? My code can catch it if you use it in  the right way.

Comment: Yes, the df only shows full rows and no exceptions

Comment: Could you provide reproducible data? Try `dput(selected_df)` and copy/paste to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately the data is too big for the question

Comment: You could just give the first 10 rows: `dput(selected_df[1:10, ])`

Comment: But it worked! Eventually I downloaded the data again and ran the test again, thank you :)

Comment: You could consider giving upvotes and picking one of the answers you prefer as accepted by clicking the check mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using `matrixStats::rowAlls`.

```
d[matrixStats::rowAlls(is.na(d[1:4]) | d[1:4] == 'F'), ]
#   col1 col2 col3 col4 length
# 3    F    F <NA> <NA>      3
# 4    F <NA> <NA> <NA>      8
# 6    F    F    F    F     10
```

Or just base R

```
d[rowSums(is.na(d[1:4]) | d[1:4] == 'F') == 4, ]
#   col1 col2 col3 col4 length
# 3    F    F <NA> <NA>      3
# 4    F <NA> <NA> <NA>      8
# 6    F    F    F    F     10
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(col1 = c("A", "F", "F", "F", "A", "F"), col2 = c("B", 
"D", "F", NA, "D", "F"), col3 = c("F", "E", NA, NA, "C", "F"), 
    col4 = c("C", "A", NA, NA, "A", "F"), length = c(15L, 12L, 
    3L, 8L, 11L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 2):

A `base` solution with `rowSums()`:

```r
df[rowSums(df[1:4] != 'F', na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ]

#   col1 col2 col3 col4 length
# 3    F    F <NA> <NA>      3
# 4    F <NA> <NA> <NA>      8
# 6    F    F    F    F     10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using functions from the [dplyr package](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/):

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "   col1 col2 col3 col4 length
1  A    B    F    C    15
2  F    D    E    A    12
3  F    F    NA   NA   3
4  F    NA   NA   NA   8 
5  A    D    C    A    11
6  F    F    F    F    10", header = TRUE)

filter(df, if_all(starts_with("col"), ~.x == "F" | is.na(.x)))
#>   col1 col2 col3 col4 length
#> 3    F    F <NA> <NA>      3
#> 4    F <NA> <NA> <NA>      8
#> 6    F    F    F    F     10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>